# Firestore Error Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath] when trying to create a Stream from Firestore

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having an issue with creating a stream based on a snapshot of Firestore objects. If I don't specify any `where` clauses, it returns nothing, and if I do, it is throwing a Firestore Error that I can't triangulate.

I don't think it's an issue with the fromJson parameters, because I have other functions that call a single habit, and they're able to get what they need just fine.

Wondering if some of you might be able to quickly spot whatever issue I have with my code here.

#### Problematic Function

This function is causing an issue, and I've tried commenting out/uncommenting the `where` clauses. If I have them commented out, the code runs fine, but nothing is generated in the stream. If I have the where clauses in (not commented out), I get the firestore error shown below the code:

```
  Stream<List<Habit>> loadActiveHabitsByUser(String userId) {
    _log.v('Trying to load all active habits by userId: $userId');
    int count = 0;
    try {
      return _habitCollectionReference
          // .where('userId' == userId)
          //  .where('isActive' == true)
          .snapshots()
          .map((snapshots) => snapshots.docs.map((doc) {
                count++;
                Habit result = doc.data() as Habit;
                _log.v('Habit with Id ${result.id} is habit #$count');
                return result;
              }).toList());
    } catch (error) {
      _log.v('A firestore error occurred loading active habits: $error');
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Here is the error I get when the where clauses (either of them) are in place:

```
The following assertion was thrown building HomeView:
Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath].
'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
Failed assertion: line 311 pos 7: 'field is String || field is FieldPath || field ==
FieldPath.documentId'
```

#### Supporting Code

The function above uses this collection reference specified at the top of the class it's in:

```
  final CollectionReference _habitCollectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('habits').withConverter<Habit>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Habit.fromJson(
                snapshot.id,
                snapshot.data()!,
              ),
          toFirestore: (habit, _) => habit.toJson());
```

I also have this other function in the same class that calls a single document based on ID, and that seems to work just fine:

```
  Future<Habit> loadHabit({required String id}) async {
    var ref = _habitCollectionReference.doc(id);

    final Habit habit = (await ref.get()).data()! as Habit;

    return habit;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why I wasn't getting any results with the initial query (where I don't filter results), but the error in question was because I was typing my where clause with equality, instead of using `isEqualTo`.

Bad (previous syntax): `.where('userId' == userId)`
Fixed syntax: `.where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)`

Here's the updated syntax:

```
  Stream<List<Habit>> loadActiveHabitsByUser(String userId) {
    _log.v('Trying to load all active habits by userId: $userId');
    int count = 0;
    try {
      return _habitCollectionReference
          .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
          .where('isActive', isEqualTo: true)
          .snapshots()
          .map((snapshots) => snapshots.docs.map((doc) {
                count++;
                Habit result = doc.data() as Habit;
                _log.v('Habit with Id ${result.id} is habit #$count');
                return result;
              }).toList());
    } catch (error) {
      _log.v('A firestore error occurred loading active habits: $error');
      throw error;
    }
  }
```